# Can I make an HTML5 game for Android?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

Ok to be more specific... can I program an android app in Java that has something like a web view to which I can point to local files on the phone?

I'm thinking about making an android game and i'm wondering if it can be done with a little HTML5 and Javascript that is locally stored on the phone. I heard something about a web view in Java and that is why I am wondering if it could work.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the other answers might be correct, there is a much simpler way:

If you know html5 programming, you can do a simple Android app that has one `Activity` containing one `WebView`. In that webview you load your index.html and there you go. You can basically do anything you would do on a normal web app.

PhoneGap and Appcelerator are for cross platform development and they provide access to the hardware (vibration, sensors etc) and they give you the possibility to build the native UI with html and javascript. For a pure WebApp they are not the correct frameworks/tools I think. I might be mistaken, but a WebGL Benchmark I wrote for PCs worked out of the box in the android browser and I justed used html5 and JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so when I came across WebView before somewhere. I plan on maybe putting the game in the android market so I need a native Java app I believe and I like programming with Javascipt and HTML5 so I think WebView just solved my problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is yes, your solution is phoneGap

http://phonegap.com/

Comment: Seems interesting when I checked it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

yes definitely, 
check out appcelerator.com, phonegap.com etc
u can probably go to google "cross platform mobile development"
there's a few neat html javascript frameworks